# Document AI Contract Processor - batchProcessDocuments ignores fieldMask

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client, cloud-document-ai

My aim is to reduce the `json` file size, which contains the base64 image sections of the documents by default.

I am using the Document AI - Contract Processor in US region, nodejs SDK.

It is my understanding that setting `fieldMask` attribute in `batchProcessDocuments` request filters out the properties that will be in the resulting `json`.
I want to keep only the `entities` property.

Here are my call parameters:

```js
const documentai = require('@google-cloud/documentai').v1;
const client = new documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(options);
let params = {
    "name": "projects/XXX/locations/us/processors/3e85a4841d13ce5",
    "region": "us",
    "inputDocuments": {
        "gcsDocuments": {
            "documents": [{
                "mimeType": "application/pdf",
                "gcsUri": "gs://bubble-bucket-XXX/files/CymbalContract.pdf"
            }]
        }
    },
    "documentOutputConfig": {
        "gcsOutputConfig": {
            "gcsUri": "gs://bubble-bucket-XXXX/ocr/"
        },
        "fieldMask": {
            "paths": [
                "entities"
            ]
        }
    }
};
client.batchProcessDocuments(params, function(error, operation) {
    if (error) {
        return reject(error);
    }
    return resolve({
        "operationName": operation.name
    });

});
```

However, the resulting `json` **is still containing the full set of data**.
[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The auto-generated documentation for the Node.JS Client Library is a little hard to follow, but it looks like the `fieldMask` should be a member of the `gcsOutputConfig` instead of the `documentOutputConfig`. (I'm surprised the API didn't throw an error)

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/documentai/latest/documentai/protos.google.cloud.documentai.v1.documentoutputconfig.gcsoutputconfig

The REST Docs are a little more clear

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentOutputConfig#gcsoutputconfig

---

Note: For a REST API call and for other client libraries, the `fieldMask` is structured as a string (e.g. `text,entities,pages.pageNumber`)

I haven't tried this with the Node Client libraries before, but I'd recommend trying this as well if moving the parameter doesn't work on its own.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#async-processor

Comment: Thanks @HoltSkinner. I am unsure to read the documentation correctly, but isn’t `fieldMask` an object with key `paths` and value an array of strings, which contradicts the documentation you quoted above?

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/iap/latest/iap/protos.google.protobuf.ifieldmask

Comment: That documentation you linked is for Identity-Aware Proxy, and it may use a different format for Field Masks.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a field mask something like this.
`fieldMask: { paths: ["pages.paragraphs", "text"] }`